Can I compute the following bilinear pairing equation?
Given $G_1 \times G_2 \mapsto G_t$,
How can I compute the following equations?
Firstly, $e(g_1^a, g_2^b) = g_t^{ab}$
After that, $(e(g_1^a, g_2^b))^{c} = g_t^{abc}$

Of course, yes! The three-party key exchange protocol is derived from the equation.

It is unclear what you are asking.  If you know how to compute $a \in G_1, b \in G_2 \rightarrow e(a, b)$ and $z \in G_t, c \in \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow z^c$, it should be straightfoward to compute everything you asked for.
